# minified JS causing ie 11 memory to grow by 1MB on page refresh

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-closure, grunt-contrib-uglify, minifiedjs

I have an application.js file that has my minified javascript. on IE11, every time I refresh my page I see 1MB heap growth until it crashes the app eventually. If I don't minify my javascript then everything is fine and the heap size stays at 250k. I tried using ufligy2JS, google-closure and UI Compressor and this behavior is consistent across all minifying tools.

Any ideas on why my heap is growing only when my js is minified?

Comment: Can you run a profiler and check where the heap is getting allocated to?
It will give you a rough idea of why so much heap is getting allocated.